# Best way to setup table(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see attached image for database/table examples.

Within my application you will access different jobs, each job you will be able to create a new document, with each document you add you will select the source, this could either be My Company, a Client or a Vendor.

Within the "Document" table I wanted to use a "source_id" column, but the information could come from one of two tables.

Should I merge the Client and Vendor tables or create an intermediary table? Or can you recommend the correct solution?

Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: Yes better merge client and vendor tables to one additional column as type with values as (client,vendor)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you mean in an intermediary table?

Comment: yes exactly make one single table for both client and vendor with columns Primary_key(id),name,type(values as a client or a vendor) and in db project set id as foreign_key(id) referencing that merged_table.id

Comment: @squatman Why you are posting the same question?

Comment: Sami, this isn't the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes better merge client and vendor tables to one additional column as type with values as (client,vendor) with id as primary key of that merged table and as a foreign key reference in DB:project

Comment: When I come to query to retrieve the name, how will the JOIN from the new table know to look in either the Client or Vendor table? I know there is a "type" column, but I can't use a WHERE to determine the table name for a JOIN can I?

Comment: You can retrieve the name like this `select db1.type,db1.name from db1.table1,db2.table2 where db1.id=db2.id and db1.type='Client';` And I told to mantain one table for client and vendor not seperate tables i.e. total no of tables in your mycompany db should be 1

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Would it be worth having a table "Company_Type" containing two entries 1 (id) Client (name), 2 (id) Vendor (name). Then in my other table I only have to store 1 or 2 as "company_type_id" rather than having Client, Client, Vendor, Vendor etc. entered through out the table?

Comment: Yes offcourse you can do it setting type_id in the one merged table and having another table type to get the type name this is similar to what we do in context of normalisation

Comment: @Gert Arnold sorry for that i have removed that comment it was just because i thought it helped i asked. from now on i would rather avoid asking the same and for the reason i asked to upvote my questions not answers actually because idk i was not able to ask questions and i dont see any of my previous questions with negative votes